# Operator acting on ONB decomposition

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Consider the following setting: Given

- a real Hilbert space $X$ with orthonormal basis $(e_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$,
- a linear (unbounded) operator $T$ with dense domain $D\subset X$ and that
- $\{e_k\colon k\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset D$.

Let $x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\alpha_ke_k\in X$. Is it true that $Tx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\alpha_kTe_k$? If not, what are suitable assumptions for it to be true?

If $T$ was bounded this would clearly be true.
I have thought about closedness: Letting $x_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\alpha_ke_k$ we have $x_n\to x$ and $x_n\in D$. To conclude $Tx_n\to Tx$ I however still need that $Tx_n$ is convergent in $X$, which I don't think needs to be true in general.

What would be a suitable assumption on the operator $T$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general this is not true:

**The case $x_n\rightarrow x$ and $Tx_n\rightarrow y$ does not imply that $Tx = y$ in general:**

Let $Y\subseteq l^2$ be the subspace

$$Y = \{(\alpha_k)_k\in l^2: \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}k\alpha_k\text{ exists and is finite.}\}$$

Define $T:Y\rightarrow l^2$ by $T(\sum \alpha_ke_k) = (\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}k\alpha_k)e_1$ then $T$ is linear and unbounded and furthermore $Te_k = 0$ for every $k$.

However if we let $x = \sum \frac{1}{k}e_k$ then $Tx = e_1$ and hence

$$T(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\beta_ke_k) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\alpha_ke_k$$
does not imply that $\alpha_ke_k = \beta_kTe_k$ in general even though $e_k$ are eigenvectors.

---

**Closed does not imply that $T(\sum_1^n \alpha_ke_k)\rightarrow \sum_{1}^{\infty} \alpha_kTe_k$ even though $\sum_1^\infty \alpha_ke_k$ exists.**

Let $T(\sum \alpha_k e_k) = \sum k\alpha_k e_k$, then as a multiplication operator $T$ is closed. However if we let $x_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}e_k$ we know that $x_n\rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}e_k$ in $l^2$ while $Tx_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}e_k$ diverges.

Comment: Thank you, this is a nice example. Of course I didn't expect the statement to be true in general, maybe not even for the "nice" class of closed operators. I don't think the operator you gave here is closed: Consider $x^{(j)}\in \ell^2$ given by $x^{(j)}_n=\frac{1}{n}$ if $n\geq j$ and $0$ otherwise. Then $x^{(j)}\to 0$ in $\ell^2$ and $Tx^{(j)}=e_1$ but $Tx^{(j)}$ does not converge to $T0=0$.

Comment: You are correct it is not closed.

Comment: How do you see that "symmetric and ONB of eigenvectors" implies the convergence? The criterion seems very strong.   
The concrete operator I am working with does not satisfy this, however I have made a different observation: it preserves the orthogonality of the basis, in the sense that $(Te_k,Te_j)=0$ for $k\not= j$. Does this help?

Comment: Moreover I think the OP assumed that x is in the domain of T, which is probably not the case for your second example